# How to store data in a TitleAreaDialog pressing OK button?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Why in the following code (part of a class that `extends TitleAreaDialog`):

```
@Override  
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {          
    super.createButtonsForButtonBar(parent);  
    this.getButton(IDialogConstants.OK_ID).addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {  
        @Override  
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {  
            okPressed();  
        }  
    });  
}  

@Override  
protected void okPressed() {  
    saveInput();  
    super.okPressed();  
}

private void saveInput(){  
    firstNameSelected = firstNameCombo.getText();  
    lastNameSelected = lastNameCombo.getText();      
}
```

I get the following exception when I press the `OK` button:

> org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed      at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)      at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)      at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)      at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:340)       at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo.getText(Combo.java:1006)

In line: `firstNameSelected = firstNameCombo.getText();` of `saveInput`?
Why is the widget disposed on selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent)` method completely. The dialog should call `okPressed` by itself.

Moreover, I think calling `super.okPressed()` isn't necessary. At least I never use it. Just call `this.close()` instead.

Here is the simple template I use:

```
public class OptionsDialog extends Dialog {

    public OptionsDialog(Shell parentShell)
    {
        super(parentShell);
        setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        setBlockOnOpen(true);
    }

    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite composite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);

        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
        layout.marginHeight = 5;
        layout.marginWidth = 10;

        composite.setLayout(layout);

        GridData gridData = new GridData();
        gridData.widthHint = 500;

        composite.setLayoutData(gridData);

        createContent();

        return composite;
    }

    private void createContent()
    {
        /* ADD WIDGETS */
    }

    protected void configureShell(Shell newShell)
    {
        super.configureShell(newShell);
        newShell.setText("Options");
    }

    public void okPressed()
    {
        /* SAVE VALUES */
        this.close();
    }

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS/ */

}
```

Comment: 1)Tried removing `super.okPressed()` but the dialog did not close on pressing `OK`.2)If I remove `createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent)` how am I suppose to register a handler for the `OK` button?

Comment: @Cratylus The dialog calls `okPressed()` itself. That's why you override this method. You can solve the "not-closing" by calling `this.close()`. Works for me

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `okPressed()` method inside `widgetSelected()`. I don't think it is necessary to call `widgetSelected()` method at all. The `okPressed()` is called by the dialog itself.

You may want to try the following code.

```
public ClassNameWhichExtendsTitleAreDialog(Shell parentShell) {
    super(parentShell);
}

@Override
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
    createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL, true);
    createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL, false);
}

@Override
protected void okPressed() {
    firstNameSelected = firstNameCombo.getText();
    lastNameSelected = lastNameCombo.getText();
    super.okPressed();
}

// A function to return the name values obtained
```